# Current state of the Gribov-Zwanziger formalism and the softly broken BRST symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, symmetry-breaking, brst

I hope to get a little bit more clarification about the topics. My confusion arises from the fact that some authors (Lavrov et al) state that a gauge theory with softly broken BRST symmetry is inconsistent. On the other hand, I was reading that the breaking of BRST invariance is a characteristic of confinement due to the confining behavior of the propagators by restriction to the Gribov region. Is there a rigorous way to restore the BRST symmetry keeping the Gribov parameter?

Comment: Hi @Julius Hagn. Which references? Which pages?